# Dynamic Table name in BigQuery:

Tags: google-bigquery, sql-insert, dynamic-tables

I am working with a live streaming data from GA4. GA4 creates a new table each day and dope the previous one, so i have only one day of data. I want to store  a history of data so I need to create a new table and by scheduling a query insert the data into new created table.
The problem I am facing right now is in creating a dynamic table name.

GA4 creates tables like today table name will be events_20230718 and tomorrow it will be events_20230719. So I have used `format_date('%Y%m%d', date_sub(current_date(), interval 0 day))` to get the suffix of the table and used concatenation to create the name of the table. And I am getting the required table name on each day. You can see the proof in the following screenshot. [Getting required table name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzhvb.png).

However while using this table name in my query raises an error which says,

> Invalid value: Table "source_table" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table). at [6:1]

The screenshot of the code is here:[Source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXK7a.png)

Answer (score 0):

Store your query as a string and use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE [query_string] to execute the dynamic query.

e.g.

```
DECLARE source_table_name string DEFAULT 'project.dataset.sourceTableName';
DECLARE query STRING;
SET query = "INSERT INTO `project.dataset.table` SELECT * FROM `" || source_table_name || "` ";
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE query;
```